# How to set up basic CiviCRM access for a user in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, roles

- I created a basic WordPress user with Author role.
- I sync'ed the user to CiviCRM and checked the corresponding Contact was created
- I edited the WordPress Access Control to grant some permissions to the Author role

[image: WordPress user config]

However when my user logs in to WordPress there is no CiviCRM menu item...
[image: Missing CiviCRM menu]
What else needs to be done?

Note that access works fine for Administrators -- but I would prefer not to give full admin rights to everyone.

This has to be something really simple -- but I'm not seeing it.... Pointers would be much appreciated

Comment: can you explain what access you are actually needing to give this type of user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the Access Control (Permissions) in WordPress section](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#access-control-permissions-in-wordpress) of the documentation.  To access the backend you need the 'CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API' permission.

You can create additional roles with other WP plugins.

Comment: Thanks @Aidan! I could not find a mention of the `CiviCRM: access CiviCRM backend and API` permission -- but it works. It's a bit of a strange permission to have to grant though, especially since it says "Give to trusted roles only." I would have expected there to be something more explicit just to grant basic access. I'll look for a way to provide feedback to the project team

Comment: I agree it's not obvious.  'Trusted' here is those you want to let have any access to the Civi backend - so not your typical end-user. Do suggestion a change to the documentation if you can make it clearer.

Comment: My confusion is that the user I am granting access to _is_ a typical end user. There does not appear to be any more restrictive permission that will just let someone view and enter data in CiviCRM. I created in issue in GitLab: https://lab.civicrm.org/documentation/docs/user-en/-/issues/454

Comment: Ok..., describe a bit more what you want them to be able to do.  Are they editing only their own data or others as well?

Comment: Ultimately I will probably need two roles: one that can edit only specific groups of contacts (and related tasks), another that would be able to add all. I think I can handle the fine-grained piece though -- my question/comment is really around getting the very basic CiviCRM access enabled. The doc does not provide the detail needed (doesn't specify the permissions needed), and it seems weird to me that I would need to assign access to the backed API in order for a user just to see the very basic menu.